# Oracle DB Just Combine Two tables Side By Side

Tags: sql, oracle

1:Table COUNTRY

```
ID NAME   
1  USA  
2  BRITAIN
```

2:Table PEOPLE

```
P_ID        P_NAME  
4           JOHN  
5           MONTY
```

Resultant table should have

```
ID   NAME        P_ID     P_NAME  
1    USA         4       JOHN  
2    BRITAIN     5       MONTY
```

Just side by side merge. Is it possible? LIKE TABLE1 | TABLE2

Comment: are jou joining them using ID?

Comment: No I dont want to join. I Just want to combine them just side by side. like              country[11]    country[12]   People[11]   people[12]     and                 country[21]    country[22]   People[21]   people[22]

Comment: they will be sorted by id? and what if people have 2 rows and country 1?

Comment: Yeah Dmitry, If Country has only 1 row then its respective resultant combination should be null. like TABLE 1 | TABLE2

Comment: look at my eddited post. Without join tables you will get a lot of combination, so join is needed but by rownum that will point on positions by which data needed to be connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example

```
with x as (
select id, name, rownum rn from country
order by id),
y as(
select p_id, p_name, rownum rn from people
order by p_id)
select id,name,p_id,p_name from x
left join y on y.rn = x.rn
union  
select id,name,p_id,p_name from y
left join x on y.rn = x.rn
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply.See updated Post ...I dont want to join.

Answer (score 3):

If I well understood your question this could work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT T1.*,ROWNUM AS R FROM COUNTRY T1) V1, 
    (SELECT T2.*,ROWNUM AS R FROM PEOPLE T2) V2
WHERE V1.R = V2.R(+)
```

But you need to know wich table is bigger and I fear you aren't going to to get reliable results

Comment: Thanks Max...It seems right approach.. see the above Dmitry's answer...I hope both leads the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
   select c.id,c.name, p.p_id, p.p_name from country c inner join people p on c.id = p.p_id;
```

Comment: See updated code. Dont need to join. Just mix all the column headers one to one irrespective of their values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRY C
INNER JOIN PEOPLE P ON C.ID = P.P_ID;
```

Updated answer :

```
Select * from #country as c , #people as p where p_id =4 and id=1 OR id = 2 and p_id=5
```

Comment: See updated code. Dont need to join. Just mix all the column headers one to one irrespective of their values.

Comment: `Select * from #country as c , #people as p where p_id =4 and id=1 OR id = 2 and p_id=5`
 For ur result it ll come. But if there is more rows the query should change .Here , the query is static. but the query should be dynamic .   Rite ? . Is this result is enough.

Comment: yeah Naveen I was in need of more dynamic way of doing this....see the above answer provided by Dmitry..It is one of the nice solutions.